# How to fix compromised permissions in cent OS?

Tags: linux

I am using cent OS 6. The permissions of my  /var/www/html directory are compromised I cant upload anything there. Can anyone please help me fixing the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd posit you are asking the wrong question.  Surely a better question would be "Why was the system compromised and how can I recover from it" (which requires a lot more details).

Further, you have not provided sufficient details as to your access to the machine or how you are trying to upload files.

A simple (AND VERY, VERY WRONG) way to fix the problem before you would be to go chmod -R 777 /var/www/html    - Which will make all files read, write and executable by anyone.  Again, this is about the worst thing you could do, but it will fix the presenting problem.

If your box has a "single user" for uploading through FTP, you may get better traction by chown -R username.apache /var/www/html; chmod -R /var/www/html/*   - This will allow username to upload using HTTP, while allowing apache to only read.  This may have unintended consequences if an apache program is trying to write a temporary file, as it will no longer be able to.

Of-course, if you are "just a user", its possible the problem you are having relates to SELinux - in which case the above won't work.   I posit that is somewhat unlikely though.  You could further kill the limited security your system has by turning off SELinux.  You can google how to do this, its not hard if you have root access.

AGAIN, THESE ARE BAD ANSWERS TO A BADLY WORDED QUESTION. YOU SHOULD NOT USE THEM.